# Hosting nextjs app to IIS as a sub application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, next.js, webserver

I want to host nextjs application under the IIS website as a sub-application, following the below video  I am able to run nextjs app as a website in IIS
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLsx0iraA-Y . i need help to host it as a sub-application.
the reason i want to host it as a sub app is i already have 5-6 asp.net websites running as sub applications under the parent site and now i want to host nextjs app under the same site.

[image]

here are the  serverjs and web.config files

server.js file

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:{port}`)
  })
})
```

web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>        
            <remove segment="node_modules"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <iisnode node_env="production" />  
    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You only need to publish your nextjs application to the sub-application directory. there will be a physical path when you create sub application nextjsapp, you need to publish your application under this folder.

Comment: @samwu I tried that. I am getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

I had to add a base path in the next.config.js file to make it work.
Now it works the same way as root application. the requests will have a sub-application after the domain

- [www.domain.com/subapplication](http://www.domain.com/subapplication)
- [www.domain.com/subapplication/aboutus](http://www.domain.com/subapplication/aboutus)
- [www.domain.com/subapplication/contactus](http://www.domain.com/subapplication/contactus)
- [www.domain.com/subapplication/api/hello](http://www.domain.com/subapplication/api/hello)

````
 module.exports = {
                basePath: '/subapplication',
                images: {
                    path: `subapplication/_next/image`,
                  },
                async rewrites() {
                    return [
                      {
                        source: '/subapplication/',
                        destination: '/subapplication/index'           
                      },
                    ]
                  },
            
              } ```
````

Comment: Best answer out here !